# Command for not making a word Latex-ified when between $$?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I am wondering if there is, or how I can make, a command that will basically accomplish the same thing as the `\gcd` command, which types gcd in normal letters when within a pair of `$`'s. I know I can use `\text{}`, but I find something like the `\gcd` command much more convenient and natural to use.

Comment: Welcome! Look for `\DeclareMathOperator` on the site

Comment: And no you cannot use `\text` this is not what that macro is for (sadly many people don't know what `\text` is for)

Comment: @daleif might be a good idea to actually tell what `\text` is for, instead of just saying: "Not that" in this case, so more people learn what `\text` is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You write that you are looking for

> a command that will basically accomplish the same thing as the `\gcd` command, which types `gcd` in normal letters when [in math mode]. ... I know I can use `\text{}` ...

That's not quite correct.

- The macros `\gcd`, `\log`, `\det`, `\sin`, etc are as math operators, meaning that not only will the letters "gcd", "log", etc be typeset using upright math-mode letters, but also that TeX will insert a bit of whitespace before and (generally) after the commands.
- The `\text` macro, in contrast, employs the document's text font to typeset its argument, in whatever the surrounding text mode happens to be. This could be "normal", i.e., upright letters. However, it could also be italics if the surrounding text mode happens to be `\itshape` or `\em`, it could bold sans-serif, etc, etc. Importantly, `\text` does *not* insert whitespace before and after its argument.

My hunch is that you're looking for either `\mathrm`, if you want the argument to be typeset using the document's upright ("roman") math font, or `\textnormal`, if you want to employ the basic (i.e., non-bold, non-italic) main text font. Actually, if you do need whitespace to surround the command's output, it's straightforward to declare a math operator via the `\DeclareMathOperator` directive. Say,

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Henry}{Henry}
```

The following test document employs Computer Modern math font, Times "roman" as the text (serif) font, and Helvetica as the text sans-serif font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,times}
\begin{document}
$2\sin\theta$  

% prevailing text font shape: upright (roman) 
$2\text{sin}\theta$

\itshape
% prevailing text font shape: slanted/italic Times Roman
$2\text{sin}\theta$

\sffamily\bfseries
% prevailing text font shape: slanted/bold Helvetica
$2\text{sin}\theta$

$2\mathrm{sin}\theta$ % upright math font

$2\textnormal{sin}\theta$ % upright serif font 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’ll note that the two most common ways for this to bite someone are: theorem statements with text in italics, and headers with text in bold. If you actually want bold text in the latter case, use `\textup`.

Comment: @Davislor - The OP mentioned wanting to output "normal letters", but didn't give any specifics as to what "normal letters" may or may not be. That's exactly why I called my suggestion nothing but a hunch.

Comment: Not disagreeing with anything you wrote, but sometimes people do want bold math in headings.

Comment: I learned how to do this with `\newcommand{\Henry}{\operatorname{Henry}}`.  Is that incorrect, or just old-fashioned?

Comment: They're both provided by the `amsmath` package.  I'm reading the docs right now, and it seems to suggest that `\operatorname` be used for one-off upright-roman operators, but if you want a new command, use `\DeclareMathOperator`.